# :hover not working with universal child selector

Tags: html, css, hover

### HTML

```
 <!-- navigation -->
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="primary-navigation underline-indicators flex">
          <li class="active">
            <a class="uppercase text-white letter-spacing-2" href="#"
              ><span>01</span>Active</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="uppercase text-white letter-spacing-2" href="#"
              ><span>02</span>Hovered</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="uppercase text-white letter-spacing-2" href="#"
              ><span>03</span>Idle</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  <!-- Tabs -->
    <div class="tab-list underline-indicators flex">
       <button
            aria-selected="true"
            class="uppercase ff-sans-cond text-accent bg-dark letter-spacing-2">
            Moon
       </button>
       <button
            aria-selected="false"
            class="uppercase ff-sans-cond text-accent bg-dark letter-spacing-2">
            Mars
       </button>
       <button
            aria-selected="false"
            class="uppercase ff-sans-cond text-accent bg-dark letter-spacing-2">
            Europa
       </button>
     </div>
```

### css

```
.underline-indicators > * {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: var(--underline-gap, 1rem) 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0);
}

.underline-indicators > *:hover,
.underline-indicators > *:focus {
  border-color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.5);
}
```

> I want to hover over all the child of number-indicators class. But its not working with universal selector (*). But the 'focus' property is working fine.

> I want to keep the universal selector because I want to use the single class in both navigation and tabs-list.

[I should be getting a hover effect in both the places.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESego.png)

> Please help me understand my mistakes

Comment: how about using `hsl` method with some other values like `hsl(0, 100%, 50%)`  ? I think your problem is not related to universal selector. actually your problem is with using css-variables.

Comment: No, it works fine if I dont use the universal selector. For example, in tabs, if I use   .underline-indicators > button   , the hover works fine. But I dont get why the universal selector is not working. Also this same code works fine in Codepen but not in regular browsers.

Comment: Take a lookt at this demo, I copied your code and edited 
`hsl` value. https://jsbin.com/detalakaxa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I found my mistake. Inclusion of meta tags solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion of the meta tag might not work sometimes so try including the  !DOCTYPE html declaration as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32626365)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).